# Blackberry Java application loading in device

Tags: blackberry-simulator

I have a developed a Java application in blackberry simulator. I need to load the Java application in Blackberry device.

What are the steps to load the application in Blackberry device?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have signing keys and your keys are installed in the JDE (Almost any non-trivial BB app needs to be signed).  Use the sigtool to sign your .cod

Use Javaloader (in the JDE's bin directory)

With your device plugged into your machine with a USB...
javaloader -usb load yourapp.cod

That will load the app onto the device, but without the application description info (you likely don't need it at this point)

http://www.blackberryforums.com/general-blackberry-discussion/3027-howto-installing-jde-use-javaloader.html